# Processing draw a rect and keep it for some time

Tags: java, processing, draw

So i've made a simple program that have as its objective to draw a rect on the screen when a button is clicked on the mouse, if its the left button it make a rect on the left half of the screen, and if it the right it make a rect in the right half of the screen.
The problem is that i used a for loop to make the rect get drew for some time continuously, but it just does not happen.

Here is my code:

```
 int bab = 0;


void setup() {
size(500, 500);
frameRate(24);
background(255);
int b = 0;


}

void draw() {
background(255);
println(bab);
bab++;
if(mousePressed == true && mouseButton == LEFT) {
fill(100, 0, 0);
for(int i = 0; i <= 20000; i++) {
  fill(100, 0, 0);
  rect(0, 200, width/2, 50);
  println("The value is: " + i);
}
background(255);
}else if(mousePressed == true && mouseButton == RIGHT) {
fill(255, 255, 0);
for(int i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
  rect(width/2, 0, width/2, height);
}
}

}
```

Comment: What should be happen what do you mean to draw continuously?

Comment: I mean make the rect keep on the screen for some time, like it draw the rect keep it some time(in this case draw the rect for 200 frames so for example) and then clear the screen.

Comment: No, you can't make the rect keep on the screen, no way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
long leftOn = 0;
long rightOn = 0;

void draw() {

  // clear window buffer (white color)
  background(255);

  if (mousePressed == true && mouseButton == LEFT) {

    // remember timestamp when left button was pressed in variable leftOn
    leftOn = millis();
    rightOn = 0;

  } else if (mousePressed == true && mouseButton == RIGHT) {

    // remember timestamp when right button was pressed
    rightOn = millis();
    leftOn = 0;

  }

  // now is current timestamp
  long now = millis();

  /*
   * if now - last left click distance is lower than 1000 ms - draw left rect
   * else if now - right left click distance is lower than 1000 ms - draw right rect
   */ 
  if (now - leftOn <= 1000*1) {
    fill(0,255,0);
    rect(0,0,width/2,height);
  } else if (now - rightOn <= 1000*1) {
    fill(255,255,0);
    rect(width/2, 0, width/2, height);
  } 

  // else - nothing is drawn in this frame, so window will be empty in this frame 

}
```

Looping is done by Processing - I mean when you set frame rate to 20 it means that Processing will call method `draw()` every 50 ms (20 times in 1 second).

So, you have to implement how 1 single frame should be drawn. You dont need looping to make things last longer.

In above code left rect will appear and last for 1 second from last left button was pressed. And right rect for 1 second from right button.

The `millis()` method returns the number of milliseconds that elapsed from startup. You can then remember in `leftOn` when left button was pressed. And you draw left rect if time difference between now and last leftOn is less then 1000 ms - for example.

Comment: Thanks it actually works, i just dont understand why my code does not work because in my mind when i loop the draw rect the processing will draw the rect multiple times(in this case stopping the draw() loop) but it just did not happen. Why? Can you explain please?

Comment: When you call `rect()` or `ellipse()` or any other painting method, this painting is done only in **buffer** (some allocated memory) - **not on screen**. When `draw()` method is finished, Processing moves that buffer **onto screen**, wait some time (ie 15ms, depending on frame rate), and call `draw()` method again...

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop uses `i` as it's control / to represent each iteration through the loop. You also have the drawing happening in this loop, so that each iteration should draw something.

**However**, *nowhere* in your loop do you *use* the `i` variable -- you only print it to the console.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 20000; i++) {
  fill(100, 0, 0); // does not use i
  rect(0, 200, width/2, 50); // does not use i
  println("O valor é: " + i);
}
```

So what you have really is a loop that draws the exact same thing, 20000 times. So to you it looks like nothing is happening, but it is, it's just the same thing is happening repeatedly.

Maybe you wanted something more like:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 20000; i++) {
      fill(100, 0 + i, 0 + i);
      rect(0 + i, 200, width/2, 50 + i);
      println("O valor é: " + i);
    }
```

^ I really have no idea if that makese sense... **But** you need to use the loop control variable `i` somewhere in your drawing code, or else yes, you will draw the same thing repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i actually want the code to repeat the exactly same thing, in this case draw the same rectangle a number of times in order to achieve the result of making the rect appears on the screen for some seconds(i.e 20 seconds) and then disappear.